# How Changefeeds feature works internally in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

I am a new user of RethinkDB. Could anyone tell me if every time that I receive changes on a table, through the Changefeeds feature, the query needs to reevaluated every time?

For example, a query that return all the users from a specified country. Two tables: users and countries. I allways want to know  all the users from that country. I ask because if my table has a lot of records (millions) could be a bit expensive...

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is... it depends on what you want to do and how your query is structured.

**#1 Simple Queries**

If you have a simple filter query that is listening for changes on all 'users' from a particular country, your query won't get reevaluated every single time. RethinkDB handles that automatically and it's not an expensive operation. In terms of performance, this is the preferred strategy.

Example:

```
r.table('users')
 .filter({ country: "China })
 .changes()
```

You can also listen to users from multiple countries in the same query:

```
var countries = [ 'China', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Mexico', 'United States' ];
r.table('users')
 .filter(function (row) {
    return r.expr(countries).contains(row('country'));
 })
 .changes()
```

**#2 Simple Queries with single join**

If, when you get an update on the user, but you also want to join the country data from the 'countries' table, you can do that after the `changes` with a `merge` and a `get`.

```
r.table('users')
 .filter({ country_name: "China })
 .changes()
 .merge(function (row) {
   return {
     'country': r.table('countries').get(row('country_name'))
   }
 })
```

This will join the data every time there's an update, but it's more expensive than the previous one because, every time there is an update, it will have to do a point read in the 'countries' table.

**#3 Alternative to #2**

If you don't want to do this, but want to still join the countries to the 'users' table, you could do the joins in your application layer.

Comment: Which one did you want to do, btw?

Comment: Well, I need to use the second one, because my data is dynamic. I have another question: If I have multiples subscriptions over the same table, the changefeeds will run sequentially or parallel?

Comment: If you have multiple subscriptions in the same table, you can't predict which one will get fired first. I guess that means it's parallel, but that seems more of an implementation detail, so I'm not sure.